# Excel VBA to replace characters - char-by-char vs regex(?)

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I've been using the following code to replace accented characters with equivalent/acceptable replacements:

```
Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿø"
Const RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyyo"


    For x = 1 To dataRange
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        y = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)  
        z = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
        ActiveCell.Replace What:=y, _
        Replacement:=z, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        MatchCase:=True
        Next i
    Next x
```

Since this is accomplished on a character-by-character basis for every cell in the range, the process becomes quite slow (QUITE!) when processing tens of thousands of records.

I've recently replaced a  different char-by-char evaluation process using regexes instead (which sped things up a bit), but I'm not sure that this particular type of evaluation and replacement process is suitable for a regex style solution.

I'm not well versed in using regexes on the VBA platform (I can do rudimentary regex functions on the sheet level) so I'm at the point where I don't know if I can't get this to work because I'm too much of a novice to get it to work, or if I can't get it to work because it is not possible to be accomplished using regexes as the solution for this.

I would appreciate any advice I could get from those who know regexes well enough to make a determination regarding this need.

Comment: Rather than activating each cell, read the entire range into an array. Process the array and output the array result in a single write. I would imagine that is the cause of speed issues. Also, you can use .Replace for a range rather than a single cell.

Comment: Thanks for the change in approach. I've never actually used range arrays in place of looping through every cell in a range (if that's bad form, then it's only because I'm self-taught and never knew that there was a different way of doing that). Therefore I'm going to test some tried and true loops to see if I can get them to work using a range array instead. Once I succeed with understanding that basic process, I'll try to tackle this particular situation using the range array approach as well.

Comment: Have a read of this http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx - A range and an array are different in VBA.

Comment: Many thanks ooo! I had no sooner mentioned to Ron that I was sketchy about the UBound parameters when I soon found the "ah-ha" answer in the link that you had shared. Very nice. Great link. Thanks very much for your help with this concept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of some VBA code using arrays and Replace. And then writing the array back to the worksheet (although in a different place in this implementation.  AccChars and RegChars need to be strings of the same length.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceAccents()
    Const AccChars As String = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿø"
    Const RegChars As String = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyyo"

    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set rSrc = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
V = rSrc

For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    For J = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        V(I, 1) = Replace(V(I, 1), Mid(AccChars, J, 1), Mid(RegChars, J, 1), compare:=vbBinaryCompare)
    Next J
Next I

rSrc.Offset(columnoffset:=5) = V

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very impressive Ron. The ability to see my real-life Replace example modified into an array solution has really allowed me understand what is taking place. The UBound parameters are still a bit sketchy in my mind, although logic would indicate that it translates to the maximum row of the range. I obviously need to delve much deeper into the supporting functions that an array can be paired with, but that will all settle in once my familiarity and my needs for array solutions expand. For now I understand the concept and I am able to modify as necessary, which is HUGE! Thanks again Ron.

Comment: Glad to help.  When you read a range into a variant array, the array becomes a 1-based 2 dimensional array where the first dimension represents the rows, and the 2 dimension represents the columns. So the outerloop processes each "row" equivalent.  It is MUCH faster to do this kind of work in a VBA array than going back and forth to the worksheet.

Comment: Yes, I've done some research and reading, and some of the mystery has already been solved for me. It'll still take some time before I can intuitively "think" in range array solutions, but you have really catapulted me forward with your help today. I apologize for the overkill of my gratitude, but seriously, you allowed me to "SEE" the solution and that has really given me the confidence to now apply it to other situations. I'll stop thanking you now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop to cycle through each letter replacement pair and plug them into this:

```
Selection.Replace What:=letterToReplace,Replacement:=replacementLetter,-
    LookAt:=xlPart,SearchOrder:=xlByRows,MatchCase:=True,SearchFormat:=False,-
ReplaceFormat:=False
```